# perl comparing 2 data file as array 2D for finding match one to one

Tags: perl, arrays

I'm doing a program that uses combinations of variables ( combiData.txt 63 rows x different number of  columns) for analysing a data table ( j1j2_1.csv, 1000filas x 19 columns ) , to choose how many times each combination is repeated in data table and which rows come from (for instance, tableData[row][4]).

I have tried to compile it , however I get the following message :

```
  Use of uninitialized value $val in numeric eq (==) at rowInData.pl line 34.
  Use of reference "ARRAY(0x1a2eae4)" as array index at rowInData.pl line 56.
  Use of reference "ARRAY(0x1a1334c)" as array index at rowInData.pl line 56.
  Use of uninitialized value in subtraction (-) at rowInData.pl line 56.
  Modification of non-creatable array value attempted, subscript -1 at rowInData.pl line 56.
nothing
```

---

This is my code:

```
      #!/usr/bin/perl
      use strict;
      use warnings;

      my $line_match;
      my $countTrue;

       open (FILE1, "<combiData.txt") or die "can't open file text1.txt\n";
       my @tableCombi;
       while(<FILE1>) {
       my @row = split(' ', $_);
       push(@tableCombi, \@row);
       }
       close FILE1 || die $!;

       open (FILE2, "<j1j2_1.csv") or die "can't open file text1.txt\n";
       my @tableData;
       while(<FILE2>) {
          my @row2 = split(/\s*,\s*/, $_);
       push(@tableData, \@row2);
       }
       close FILE2 || die $!;

      #function transform combiData.txt variable (position ) to the real value that i have to  find in the data table.
      sub trueVal($){
      my ($val) = $_[0];
      if($val == 7){ return ('nonsynonymous_SNV'); }
      elsif( $val == 14)          { return '1'; }
      elsif( $val == 15)   { return '1';}
      elsif( $val == 16)    { return '1'; }
      elsif( $val == 17)        { return '1'; }
      elsif( $val == 18)      { return '1';}
      elsif( $val == 19)     { return '1';}
      else              { print 'nothing'; }
      }

     #function  IntToStr ( ) , i'm not sure if it is necessary) that transforms $ to strings  ,     to use the function <eq> in the third loop for the array of combinations compared with the data  array .
     sub IntToStr { return "$_[0]"; } 



     for my $combi (@tableCombi) {
     $line_match = 0;

         for my $sheetData (@tableData) {
        $countTrue=0;

       for my $cell ( @$combi) {
             #my $temp =\$tableCombi[$combi][$cell] ;
         #if ( trueVal($tableCombi[$combi][$cell] )  eq $tableData[$sheetData][ $tableCombi[$combi][$cell] - 1 ]   ){
         #if ( IntToStr(trueVal($$temp )) eq IntToStr( $tableData[$sheetData][ $$temp-1] ) ){
         if ( IntToStr(trueVal($tableCombi[$combi][$cell]) )  eq IntToStr($tableData[$sheetData][ $tableCombi[$combi][$cell] -1])  ){
            $countTrue++;}
         if ($countTrue==@$combi){
            $line_match++;
            #if ($line_match < 50){
            print $tableData[$sheetData][4]." ";
            #}
         }  

     }
  }
print $line_match." \n";
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this code:

```
for my $combi (@tableCombi) {
     $line_match = 0;
     for my $sheetData (@tableData) {
         $countTrue=0;
         for my $cell ( @$combi) {
```

You are iterating on the values, not the indexes of the array.

You should do:

```
for my $combi (@tableCombi) {
     $line_match = 0;
     for my $sheetData (@tableData) {
         $countTrue=0;
         for my $cell ( @$combi) {
             if (IntToStr(trueVal($cell)) eq IntToStr($sheetData->[$cell-1])){
                 $countTrue++;
             }
             if ($countTrue == @$combi){
                 $line_match++;
                 print $tableData[$sheetData][4]." ";
             }  
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: your suggestion works, however when I use combinations that use  "19", matches that include this value (1 in the @tableData)don't appear , I know that these specific combinations (with "19") have matches due to i checked it using excel filters

Comment: 7, 14, 15 ...19 refer to columns in the tableData, that is, 19 is the 19th column

Answer (score 0):

First, i would add `return(0);` to `trueVal()` in the cases where that should be returned. Just nicer to read.

Your main problem however seems to be line 52 (seriously, add line numbers if you want people to understand your error messages). `@$combi` is an array ref. Not an array. As the error messages clearly state, by the way. I assume you wanted it to be an array of the words of `$combi`? If so, just add another line like

```
my @combiArray = split (/ +/, $combi);
```

and have `$cell` iterate through that.
Replace `/ +/` if those entries are seperated by something different than one or more spaces. 
There really might be a way to archieve this within the same line, but just because Perl allows to put severals operations into one line does not mean you have to do that.